# Joomla singular and plural view names

Tags: joomla-3.4, view

Is there a built in functionality available in joomla to determine the view name to plural?

I created 2 views as 'delivery' and 'deliverys'.  The view 'delivery' is to display the records in a list view using default.php and the view 'deliverys' is to display one single records using edit.php.

When I hit the cancel button in the list view it redirects to a view called 'deliveries' and since I have the view name as 'deliverys' it says view not found.

Just want to understand is this a built in feature in Joomla to determine the plural name for a given view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take a look at [this if statement](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/e33857bbe74ea8e062613902869415bfd4afcb2b/libraries/legacy/controller/form.php#L105) in `JControllerForm` class.

So to redirect to `deliverys`, you have to add property

```
protected $view_list = 'deliverys';
```

in your controller. If this dosen't exist, Joomla! tries to determine view name by itself.

And ofcourse, other solution would be to rename your view.

I think you have `delivery` view for one record and `deliverys` for list view, not vice versa?

Comment: Yes, delivery for one single record and deliverys for multiple records.